# notifydatasetchanged returns null

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Hey guys I get a nullpointerexception when I try to update the listview from another thread. I am able to do this just fine on my main activity, but I want update listview from another class thread, I was wondering what am I doing wrong, and could it be something I am overlooking? Here is the code. Sorry for the messy code, I have been at this for hours here is the server class. I have tried so many different things I don't remember everything I tried.

Server:

```
public class Server extends Thread{

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private ServerGUI gui;
    Context context;
    private Server s;
    ArrayList<String> addclientlist;
    private ListView listview;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String inforeceive;




    public Server(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        gui = new ServerGUI();
        listview = (ListView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.list);




    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        gui.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{

                    int port = 8000;
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                    TextView listport = (TextView)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.textViewportlisten);
                    listport.setText("Listening On Port: "+serverSocket.getLocalPort());

                    addclientlist = new ArrayList<String>();
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(gui,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, addclientlist);
                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);




                }catch(Exception e){

                }
                setOnline();




            }
        });

        super.run();
    }




    public void setOnline(){

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{


                    while(true){

                        final Socket cs = serverSocket.accept();

                        final DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(cs.getInputStream());

                        gui.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {


                                    final EditText logtext = (EditText) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.editTextlog);
                                    logtext.append("New client from: " + cs.getInetAddress() + "\n");

                                    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>(){
                                        @Override
                                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                            return null;
                                        }

                                        @Override


                                        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                                            try{
                                                adapter.add(dis.readUTF().toString());
                                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                dis.close();
                                            }catch(Exception e){
                                                logtext.append(e.toString()+"\n");
                                            }
                                            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                                        }
                                    }.execute();
                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                }
                            }
                        });


                    }

                }catch(IOException e){

                }
            }
        }).start();



    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `ServerGUI`? You need to do UI updates on the main UI thread. See the documentation for some examples: [Communicating with the UI Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html).

Comment: ServerGUI I just named as the mainactivity

Comment: Why are you calling `new Activity()` then? You should get the reference to the activity from something else.

Comment: if you mean ServerGUI gui; is because when I use ServerGUI i get "not an enclosing class" thrown at me.

Comment: Your activity should be created by Android and then you pass a reference to it into your `Server` class.

Comment: It is, all I did was rename my activity that is it. server class is not an activity if you didn't notice.

Comment: That's weird that you are then creating it in the second line of your `Server` constructor.... `gui = new ServerGUI()`.  Looks like more than a simple rename to me.  Good luck in finding your issue though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60726/discussion-between-andyadd-and-chris).